# Transpose rows into columns when rows are dynamic -MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to transpose the rows into columns and the number of rows is dynamic.
I have checked some of the questions, they are using `CASE` in mysql by using the static values. In my case, the values would be dynamic. Here is my structure:

[image]

I will be querying the table as `where meeting_id=1`, I am trying to get output like this:

```
meeting_id, first_name, last_name, occupation
         1, danyal    , sandeelo , engineer
```

Comment: Problems of data display are generally best handled in application level code, if that's available

Comment: I have multiple joins, when this data is obtained, I will basically join other tables with it @Strawberry

Comment: That's fine. You can handle the joins in MySQL. But handle the output display in application code.

Comment: Using a number of apis, I am using Nayjest in laravel. I just pass the names of columns and the grid is generated. I will have to re-work since the same grid is used in a number of pages @Strawberry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) and [Prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to handle dynamic number of fields in MySQL Pivot.

Please find query below with some test data.

> Prepare Data

```
CREATE TABLE Meeting
(
    ID INT,
    Meeting_id INT,
    field_key VARCHAR(100),
    field_value VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (1, 1,'first_name' , 'danyal');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (2, 1,'last_name' , 'sandeelo');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (3, 1,'occupation' , 'engineer');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (4,2,'first_name' , 'John');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (5,2,'last_name' , 'Matthew');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (6,2,'occupation' , 'engineer');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Meeting_id,field_key,field_value)
VALUES (7,2,'field4' , 'xyz');
```

> SQL Query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when field_key = ''',
      field_key,
      ''' then field_value end) ',
      field_key
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Meeting;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Meeting_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Meeting 
                   GROUP BY Meeting_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I will like to know I thing more. Is there any way to have joins with the Statements?

Comment: You can modify final select statement to include JOINS and other referred columns. Also you would need to add additional columns in Group By clause.